# Integrating ssl to shared hosting server

Tags: ssl, shared-hosting

I own a domain name from godaddy.

Now, I want to host the domain with SSl support.
Is it possible to get hosting and ssl certificate from two different vendors and then integrate them with my domain as i am going to have shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Please check answer here
https://serverfault.com/questions/405750/godaddy-ssl-on-shared-hosting

Yes, you can buy domain name and SSL from two different vendors.
Note: Please must mentioned the exact domain name when buying the SSL certificate.

Please check the following also,
http://www.webhostinghero.com/install-godaddy-ssl-certificate-on-cpanel/

Comment: Main concern here is to integrate that ssl into shared hosting .. will it be possible in any way

Comment: Acutally you can do it now for free using the free Certs by Let'sEncrypt via Acme.sh and you can install them using the CPanel UAPI

https://east.fm/posts/acme-sh-cpanel-a2hosting/index.html